# Flash Stage Video component for OpenLaszlo

Tags: flash, video, openlaszlo, lzx

Is there are video component for OpenLaszlo utilizing [Flash Stage Video](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/stagevideo.html)? Stage video support has been around since [Flash Player 10.2](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/release-note/release-notes-flash-player-10-2.html). According to Adobe, Processor usage can reduced by up to 85% using Stage Video.

For details on Flash Video, check this [Adobe Flash Player Team blog post](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2011/02/flash-player-10-2-launch.html), and the Adobe TV recoding of [MAX Sneaks : Flash Player Video Performance Improvements](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=geK7geL3I40).

Comment: It seems like there is no existing component with Flash Stage Video support.